# ad mob ad displaying under button but not under viewdidload

Tags: ios, swift, button, viewdidload, interstitial

The following code is of admob interstitial... When put under IBAction of button, it pops up ad but does not when I put the code in viewdidload

I am new to swift programming so please tell me how to make sure that the following code is executed as soon as the view opens

```
if (self.interstitial.isReady)
{
    self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
    self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried viewWillAppear or viewWillAppear??

Try:

```
     override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

      super.viewDidAppear(true)


   if self.interstitial.isReady
      {
       self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
       self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but when I put this, the ad appears again and again... I mean, even if I press cross button, it reappears

Comment: after this use viewDidDisappear

Comment: whenever your view will appear this method will call every time

Comment: But when should viewDidDisappear be put... Because the ad pops when game is over, game score needs to be displayed after it. Can you please help by telling where to place this method? Thanks! Another strange thing, the code u told above does not work the first time, but then pops up again and again 2nd time onwards.

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you are trying so i can also tell you other ways to do it.

Comment: I have a game. Once the game is over, I use a segue to go to game over view. I want an ad to pop up as soon as new view opens

Comment: The logic is you cannot load the new viewcontroller on viewdid load. so you have to write it in view did appear with a bollean taken that it should set false after first run...i think you understand if not i will send you the code

Comment: if checkFirstrun==nil
{
checkFirstrun = true
//Write your code here for interstitial ad
}
try to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are loading the ad before you request it. This may be why the ad will appear when pushing the button but not in `view DidLoad`. I am guessing you are loading the ad in `viewDidload`. Make sure that you call...

```
if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
    self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
    self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
}
```

after you have loaded the ad. You will find a great tutorial on creating a swift adMob interstitial here http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/4/16/admob-71-interstitial-ads-in-swift-xcode-63-ios-83 It is short, easy to follow, and should hopefully help you make sure you are doing it correctly. Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah you should just have to put that code that is within the button action into the `viewDidLoad` method but underneath loading the ad.